# 10G NIC ethernet dropped/overrun counter

Tags: linux, kernel, network-interface, ethernet

We have 2x10G NICs configured in a `bond` interface and we are seeing randomly:

`RX errors 28751549  dropped 46541  overruns 28751549  frame 0`

We do have multiple VLANs running on this NIC so its a trunk port.

The NIC is a `Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM57810 10 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)`

I have the following RX ring buffer size. Not sure where it comes from.

```
# ethtool -g eno49
Ring parameters for eno49:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:         4078
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:         4078
Current hardware settings:
RX:         407
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:         4078
```

some statistics:

```
# ethtool -S eno49 | grep rx
     [0]: rx_bytes: 35806944147
     [0]: rx_ucast_packets: 254721712
     [0]: rx_mcast_packets: 109111
     [0]: rx_bcast_packets: 26
     [0]: rx_discards: 3599652
     [0]: rx_phy_ip_err_discards: 0
     [0]: rx_skb_alloc_discard: 0
     [0]: rx_csum_offload_errors: 341
     [1]: rx_bytes: 35586576857
     [1]: rx_ucast_packets: 251529817
     [1]: rx_mcast_packets: 0
     [1]: rx_bcast_packets: 0
     [1]: rx_discards: 3586872
     [1]: rx_phy_ip_err_discards: 0
     [1]: rx_skb_alloc_discard: 0
     [1]: rx_csum_offload_errors: 127
     [2]: rx_bytes: 35580155284
     [2]: rx_ucast_packets: 251785183
     [2]: rx_mcast_packets: 0
     [2]: rx_bcast_packets: 0
     [2]: rx_discards: 3584128
     [2]: rx_phy_ip_err_discards: 0
     [2]: rx_skb_alloc_discard: 0
     [2]: rx_csum_offload_errors: 125
     [3]: rx_bytes: 35614282304
     [3]: rx_ucast_packets: 251757796
     [3]: rx_mcast_packets: 0
     [3]: rx_bcast_packets: 0
     [3]: rx_discards: 3587512
     [3]: rx_phy_ip_err_discards: 0
     [3]: rx_skb_alloc_discard: 0
     [3]: rx_csum_offload_errors: 161
     [4]: rx_bytes: 35547320461
     [4]: rx_ucast_packets: 251679615
     [4]: rx_mcast_packets: 0
     [4]: rx_bcast_packets: 0
     [4]: rx_discards: 3596817
     [4]: rx_phy_ip_err_discards: 0
     [4]: rx_skb_alloc_discard: 0
     [4]: rx_csum_offload_errors: 1171
     [5]: rx_bytes: 36582099166
     [5]: rx_ucast_packets: 253331335
     [5]: rx_mcast_packets: 0
     [5]: rx_bcast_packets: 0
     [5]: rx_discards: 3590358
     [5]: rx_phy_ip_err_discards: 0
     [5]: rx_skb_alloc_discard: 0
     [5]: rx_csum_offload_errors: 982
     [6]: rx_bytes: 35710085729
     [6]: rx_ucast_packets: 252379427
     [6]: rx_mcast_packets: 0
     [6]: rx_bcast_packets: 0
     [6]: rx_discards: 3589068
     [6]: rx_phy_ip_err_discards: 0
     [6]: rx_skb_alloc_discard: 0
     [6]: rx_csum_offload_errors: 745
     [7]: rx_bytes: 166064885960
     [7]: rx_ucast_packets: 418819356
     [7]: rx_mcast_packets: 0
     [7]: rx_bcast_packets: 0
     [7]: rx_discards: 3617142
     [7]: rx_phy_ip_err_discards: 0
     [7]: rx_skb_alloc_discard: 0
     [7]: rx_csum_offload_errors: 161
     rx_bytes: 416492349908
     rx_error_bytes: 0
     rx_ucast_packets: 2186004241
     rx_mcast_packets: 109111
     rx_bcast_packets: 26
     rx_crc_errors: 0
     rx_align_errors: 0
     rx_undersize_packets: 0
     rx_oversize_packets: 0
     rx_fragments: 0
     rx_jabbers: 0
     rx_discards: 28751549
     rx_filtered_packets: 7716855
     rx_mf_tag_discard: 0
     rx_brb_discard: 0
     rx_brb_truncate: 0
     rx_pause_frames: 0
     rx_mac_ctrl_frames: 0
     rx_constant_pause_events: 0
     rx_phy_ip_err_discards: 0
     rx_skb_alloc_discard: 0
     rx_csum_offload_errors: 3813
```

How do I trace this issue? It is happening on multiple servers, not in a single machine. We don't have that much traffic to fill the link also.

Comment: Well, first up is probably to find any commonalities. Does it happen only with particular kernel versions? Only on a single switch? Etc.

Comment: I just check on network monitor and found when etherror spotted at the same time my packets/second spiked up to `120k/s` normal traffic is under `1k/s` look like some bust traffic coming periodically. Should increasing NIC `RX buffer size` will help to reduce these error?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't ever used 10gig hardware. Sounds like something worth testing. Also, you should probably edit your question to include that additional information (that the drops correspond to a 120,000pps spike).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the "Current hardware settings" to the maximum allow value.

```
ethtool -G eno49 rx 4078
```